# Skyhook c# wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, positioning

Does anyone know of a functional Skyhook Wireless API wrapper written in C#/VB that I could use as a reference point for my own integration?  There was a single post last year that referenced an API, but the links to it have now gone dead.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the post I was referencing: [Skyhook API/StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323165/is-there-a-good-framework-sdk-on-wifi-positioning-with-c)

Comment: this should really be a comment, not a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good framework/sdk on wifi positioning with c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323165/is-there-a-good-framework-sdk-on-wifi-positioning-with-c)

Comment: I referenced that post in my question...I know it's similar, but the information it presents is no longer valid.  Also it's a tangential question.

Comment: have you tried contacting the author of that blog?

Comment: Look at this on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32301/Using-the-Skyhook-Wireless-XPS-Positioning-Service)

Answer (score 0):

The best example of Skyhook using managed code (c#) can be found in the article by Joel Ivory Johnson on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32301/Using-the-Skyhook-Wireless-XPS-Positioning-Service).

There may be some changes in the Skyhook API since the article was posted so you may have to refactor some parts of the code.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but since I posted this question, I have subsequently rolled my own solution using a c++ shim and some P/Invoke.

Comment: It will be nice if you can share your code here with the community. Please accept an entry as answer, if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: The code is proprietary unfortunately, and your answer did not further my understanding, the article you referenced was mentioned in a comment posted beneath my question.  Nevertheless, thank you for taking a look at it.